# How to check with associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an Event model and a Service model I have to return Event records based on the parameters. I have two parameters `city and service`. City is present in Event model and service is the service name which is in the Service model. I have tried the following:

```
Event.all.map{|event| event.city == params[:city] && event.services.map{|service| service.where("lower(name) LIKE ?", "#{params[:service]} %")}}
```

But no luck so far if anyone could help that would be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `joins` to add an `INNER JOIN` clause to your query and this way get access to the services related to each event. Having that, you can use their `name` column and filter them using ActiveRecord:

```
Event.joins(:services)
     .where(city: params[:city])
     .where('LOWER(services.name) LIKE ?', "#{params[:service]}%")
```

Comment: Thank you, you are a life saver :)